# Window managers on Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, window-manager, 23.04, tiling

I want to start trying out different window managers. But before trying it out I want to know if I can still use my other desktop environments. I am talking about choosing between my desktop environments (gnome and xfce) at the login screen. If that is possible, will I run into problems that usually happens when installing multiple desktop environments (like conflicting settings, overwritten system themes etc...)

Note: what I want is installing window manager separate from my existing DE's.

Comment: For most the answer is No you won't run into problems, for some desktop environments they are written & only reliably work with specific (*including a single!*) window manager. LXQt is one desktop that is WM *agnostic* as the team put it, ie. it'll work with any.. but not all DEs are tested, nor designed to work with any WM being specifically written for a specific WM.  I'm unsure if you're asking only about Xfce & GNOME though.. I've never had issues with the ~6 WM's I've used with Xfce (*but won't have tested all WMs with it; I have 5 only currently installed & usually only use 4 in QA*)

Comment: I'll add I've probably only tried 3 with GNOME (with most testing related to `openbox` & GNOME).   Also note that the features you may expect to work in a DE can change how they operate when you change WM.  Again using LXQt as example; Lubuntu code their additional features they add to LXQt specifically for `openbox`, so if it's replaced - you lose those coded `openbox` *hotkeys* etc.. thus the experience can change when you change WM, but the DE still works (*just may not be identical due to WM change*)

Comment: mixing kde with gnome is going to get messry. all other probably will work fairly well. Do check out the new cinnamon and ofc. budgie (using gnome2).

Comment: I don't see how the extra Note: is helpful; eg. I installed my *extra* WMs via `sudo apt install fluxbox` to install the fluxbox WM... likewise `blackbox` etc... That doesn't change how they interact with specific DEs, nor consequences when a DE is made to work with WM.

Comment: By doing sudo apt install fluxbox will I be using fluxbox on top of my existing desktop environment or can I use it separately without depending on a DE. @guiverc

Comment: That will install the `fluxbox` package & WM to your system, but it won't be used until you login [*with it*] or tell a desktop to use it... ie. Xfce & GNOME will happily ignore the package as they're not configured to use it..  You can select it at login (ie. use `fluxbox` alone without DE), but again the DEs you have need to be told to use it.  Xfce of course is intended to be used with the `xfwm4` WM though Xfce allows that to be changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the answer is No; you won't run into problems.

Do note some desktop environments are written & only reliably work with specific (*including a single*) window manager. LXQt is one desktop that is WM agnostic as the LXQt team put it, ie. it'll work with any.. but not all DEs are tested, nor designed to work with any WM

I really like Xfce, and recall using ~6 WMs with Xfce (*but note I won't have tested all WMs with it; I have 5 only currently installed & usually only use 4 in QA*)

I'll also add I've probably only tried 3 with GNOME (*with most my testing related to `openbox` & GNOME*).

Also note that the features you may expect to work in a DE can change how they operate when you change WM. Again using LXQt as example (*I'm a Lubuntu team member thus know it probably best*), Lubuntu code their additional features they add to LXQt specifically for `openbox`, so if it's replaced - you lose those coded `openbox` hotkeys etc.. thus the experience can change when you change WM, but the DE still works (*just may not be identical due to WM change*)

You can install extra WMs via a simple

`sudo apt install fluxbox`

to install the `fluxbox` WM... likewise `blackbox` etc... That doesn't change how they interact with specific DEs, nor consequences when a DE is made to work with WM. That will install the `fluxbox` package & WM to your system, but it won't be used until you login [*with it*] or tell a desktop to use it... ie. Xfce & GNOME will happily ignore the package as they're not configured to use it.. You can select it at login (ie. use `fluxbox` alone without DE), but again the DEs you have need to be told to use it. Xfce of course is intended to be used with the `xfwm4` WM (*the WM of the Xfce Project*) though Xfce allows that to be changed.

Comment: This is really just my comments added as *answer* (*slight clean up to aid reading*)... I'm not sure I see *value* in this, but its how I see things & is somewhat based on edits & further comments from the OP.

Comment: Some of my interest with `openbox` & GNOME was due to openbox being heavily used by the Lubuntu team, and we received *complaints* that it no longer worked (with other DEs) when we switched from LXDE to LXQt.. I did more QA-testing on it awhile (with GNOME etc).  Openbox is also included with Ubuntu-MATE (*for some releases anyway*).  Alas I'm no expert with switching out WMs with GNOME as have had little interest with that sorry.

Comment: I'll also add the manual link for the current *stable* Lubuntu Manual (ie. 23.04) which shows how you change the WM on Lubuntu & LXQt anyway (*just look at first picture*) - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html  The WM is a *drop down* menu which lets you select which WM the next login will use (with it offering to change to whatever WMs are installed).  Again I'm using this Lubuntu as example as it's easy for me... I know where to find the links easier than I do, compared to say Xfce...

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can install multiple window managers and then switch between them during log in. Expect no issues at all if it concerns only window managers, i.e. tiling wm's like i3, dwm, ... or a floating window manager like Openbox. Essentially, this will be entirely free of trouble.

It is different, though when installing different desktop environments. Then expect that many utilities with the same function (e.g. editors, etc.) will clutter up your application menu. Installing a desktop environment may also change your Plymouth boot screen and your login manager. While all that can be corrected, undoing undesired changes requires manual intervention and some know-how of where to look (e.g. changing a login manager or a Plymouth boot screen).